# Search with LIKE in a 'AS' column

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT  spelers.spelerscode,
                    spelers.voornaam,
                    spelers.achternaam,
                    CASE spelers.positie
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Keeper'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Verdediger'
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Middenvelder'
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'Aanvaller'
                        WHEN 5 THEN 'Coach'
                  END AS positie,
                  elftallen.elftal_naam,
                  (SELECT COUNT(spelerscode) FROM teams WHERE spelers.spelerscode = teams.spelerscode) AS gekozen
    FROM          spelers
    LEFT JOIN     elftallen
    USING         (elftallen_id)
    LEFT JOIN     teams
    USING         (spelerscode)
    WHERE         spelerscode LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR            elftal_naam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR            positie LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR            voornaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR            achternaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    ORDER BY      spelerscode
```

When I search on 'Keeper' for example, I want to show all the keepers.
With this query it gives me no results..
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you search on `WHERE spelers.positie = 1`?

Comment: @Jonny . . . You should turn that into an answer, with a bit of explanation on why it works but not the OP's version.

Comment: @Jonny yes that is possible.

Comment: Is the actual problem that you are replacing `%$zoekwoord%` (search word?) with "keeper" and you can't actually search for 1, 2, ...? Sorry, that was not obvious to me the first read-through.

Comment: If I search on '5' I can find all the coaches (positie 5 = coach), but also all the 'spelerscodes' and all the teams (=elftallen) containing a 5... Now I want to search on 'Keeper' for example, but  it returns no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment and it really should be Jonny's answer.  But, the answer is worth some explanation.

You defined the new variable as `as positie`, you have *renamed* a column already recognized by the `from` clause.  You are expecting other references in the SQL statement to reference the new definition.  However, column aliases defined in a `select` are not available anywhere else in the `select`, in the `from`, or the `where` clauses.  (In MySQL they are available in `group by`, `having`, and `order by`, but the standard only specifies that the `order by` needs to recognize them.)

So, when you say:

```
WHERE positie LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
```

You are really saying:

```
WHERE spelers.positie LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
```

And you would clearly recognize this as never matching.

There are a bunch of different solutions:

- A Jonny suggests, just use `spelers.positie = 1`.
- Repeat the `case` logic in the `where` clause (although I consider this to be ugly, so it is my least favorite solution).
- Use a reference table and a `join` instead of `case` logic to convert the position number to a position name.
- Use enumerated types and only refer to the name throughout the code.
- Use a `having` clause:  `having positie LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'`.  The `having` clause *can* refer to aliases, although I would still change the name of the alias so the number and name have different values.

Comment: The `HAVING` is a very neat solution

Comment: I chose to create a reference table. Thank you all for answering so  fast!

Answer (score 1):

So you want the query to show records with positie 1 when one searches for Keeper? You cannot use an alias name of the SELECT clause in your WHERE clause. So you must use the same CASE clause in your WHERE clause as you are using in your SELECT clause.

```
WHERE   spelerscode LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR  elftal_naam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR  CASE spelers.positie
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Keeper'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Verdediger'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Middenvelder'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Aanvaller'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Coach'
        END  LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR  voornaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
    OR  achternaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
ORDER BY spelerscode;
```

Just a side remark: It might be good to have a table for the positions, rather than secretely knowing that 1 means keeper and 2 means defender and having to remember this in every other query and never confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions:

1: Put it the `CASE` in a `SUBSELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT  spelers.spelerscode,
                spelers.voornaam,
                spelers.achternaam,
                CASE spelers.positie
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Keeper'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'Verdediger'
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'Middenvelder'
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'Aanvaller'
                    WHEN 5 THEN 'Coach'
              END AS positie,
              elftallen.elftal_naam,
              (SELECT COUNT(spelerscode) FROM teams WHERE spelers.spelerscode = teams.spelerscode) AS gekozen
  FROM          ...
  ) as subselectTable
WHERE         spelerscode LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            elftal_naam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            positie LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            voornaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            achternaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
ORDER BY      spelerscode
```

2: Create a "translation table"...

```
Code Description
----------------
1    Keeper
2    Verdediger
...
```

and join it on...

```
SELECT DISTINCT spelers.spelerscode,
                spelers.voornaam,
                spelers.achternaam,
                translationTable.Description AS positie,
                elftallen.elftal_naam,
              (SELECT COUNT(spelerscode) FROM teams WHERE spelers.spelerscode = teams.spelerscode) AS gekozen
FROM          spelers
LEFT JOIN     elftallen
USING         (elftallen_id)
LEFT JOIN     teams
USING         (spelerscode)
JOIN          translationTable
ON            spelers.positie = translationTable.Code
WHERE         spelerscode LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            elftal_naam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            translationTable.Description LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            voornaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
OR            achternaam LIKE '%$zoekwoord%'
ORDER BY      spelerscode
```

3. Do the translation in the WHERE like Thorsten Kettner suggests